# bge keeps on crashing when I try to do soft-body simulations?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, physics, soft-body

I've written a script that creates an environment with various physics types-it generates a fair number of soft body objects (>100) and, unfortunately, when I try to run the sim, blender crashes. Any way to fix this?

Comment: My guess is that BGE runs out of ram. Does the thing dramatically slow down before crashing or go go poof right when the simulation starts?

Comment: yeah, it slows down dramatically, i'm going to try it on a computer with more ram so we'll see

Comment: A slightly more practical test would be to set the draw type to Bounding Box and see what happens. Also in my experience softbodies and meshes with bounds set to Convex Huull or Triangle Mesh are quite memory-expensive.

Comment: Also, does the simulation need to be different every time? You could try to bake part of the objects (if they are there at the start of the simulation) to keyframes and have them be on rails. To bake the frames, you can go to game > record animation and hit P.